# freeradius exec script triggered with interim-update

Tags: exec, freeradius

I would like to trigger the accounting interim-update on freeradius and then exec a script to performe a calculation about the total data volume usage related a specific user.
Could anyone help me with some example?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure that's pretty simple

Put the contents of the accounting block below into `raddb/sites-available/default` and modify as necessary.

```
accounting {
    if (Acct-Status-Type == 'Interim-Update') {
        update request {
            Tmp-Integer-0 := `/path/to/my/script.sh %{Acct-Input-Octets} %{Acct-Output-Octets} %{Acct-Session-Time}`
        }         
    }
}
```